# Verify ADFS account active C#

Tags: c#, windows, adfs, ws-trust

I want to check if my ADFS account is still active in C#. I request an RST token which I wanted to use to issue a new token and if this fails I want to display a message that their account it disabled.

The problem is that if I request a securitytoken via WS-Trust usernamemixed and  delete the account that I requested the token with the securitytoken remains active to issue new tokens.

Is there any other way to verify if an ADFS account is still active from C# via an endpoint for example.

Comment: I am afraid there is no such feature in the ws-trust, also, if you only have a token (rather than the username/password), no other endpoint will help you. The only workaround this could be to issue short-lived tokens (an hour? less?) so that they become invalid after some period of time (and you don't bother the time gap between the moment the account has been deleted and the moment the token expires).

Comment: Do you know of any way to see if an account is still active like a certain endpoint or a Custom Claim Description for example? There must be a way to see if an account is still active in ADFS via an endpoint right?

Comment: No, there is not, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed but it's not an ADFS function.

You need to query AD directly via LDAP calls.

Comment: Exactly. AD FS isn't _required_ to talk to AD at all. It can connect to any SAML identity provider. AD is just (by far) the most common.

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction and got my system working.